# Can I install ubuntu mobile on my cellphone acer E101?

Tags: 12.04, phone, ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware will the Ubuntu Mobile OS support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support)

Hi I would like to know if there is a version of ubuntu mobile so that I can remove windows mobile 6.5 and install ubuntu mobile .And I would like to know how to install it .