# Will Ubuntu mobile have support for widgets on the home screens?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Will Ubuntu mobile have support for widgets on the home screens? If so what technologies should developers be researching in order to develop new widgets? Would they simply be QML Components that can be added at runtime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware will the Ubuntu Mobile OS support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support). The answer also applies to this question.

Comment: @Web-E Currently, I cannot see how that answers this.

Comment: Nothing is revealed

Comment: ^ it is not a duplicate, But in the current state only the ubuntu phone devs can answer this question

Comment: Not only the community does't have an answer because no one knows, really. If you would take a look at how Ubuntu Mobile set up the screens, where would you put widgets?.