# Ubuntu On the New Sony Z

Tags: ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware will the Ubuntu Mobile OS support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support)

about the New Ubuntu for phones is it going to support the New Android phones Such as Sony Z that was reviewed in the there CES 2013

Answer (score 1):

1. Officially it is totaly unclear which Phones will run Ubuntu OS.
2. From a technical site: Ubuntu for Phones uses Android Kernels. This means it is theoretical possible to make it work on every Android device meeting the minimum specs. The real question is: Will the Manufacturers support installation of any other OS than their own?

There are Manufacturer limitations, such as closed bootloaders or licenses that forbid installation of OS software.

To make an unofficially statement: There will be the possibility for developers and tech-enthusiasts to install Ubuntu for phones on the Samsung Nexus Galaxy at the end of February 2013. As time goes by, there will be people trying and sharing their knowledge about installing Ubuntu on other Android phones for sure. In 2014 you will finally be able to buy an mobile with Ubuntu preinstalled.