# Ubuntu Phone for Nokia N9

Tags: nokia, ubuntu-phone, meego

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware will the Ubuntu Mobile OS support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support)

Will Ubuntu for Phones work on Nokia N9? As you might know, Nokia N9 runs MeeGo (Linux based) but it was completely abandoned since Windows 8 Nokias. It is a great phone, but the OS has and "Alpha" feel. If Ubuntu for Phone will be available for Nokia N9, I think most users will switch to Ubuntu.