# Will Ubuntu for phone run well on a Samsung Galaxy Tab2 with 3G?

Tags: samsung, ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware will the Ubuntu Mobile OS support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support)

I want to buy a tablet, however I want a tablet that I can also use for phone calls (without VOIP services).

So I'm asking if a Samsung Tab2 will run it well and with all the functions of a normal cellphone from Ubuntu?