# Ubuntu Phone on Pantech

Tags: ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware will the Ubuntu Mobile OS support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support)

I really admire the Pantech Line-up with the cheap unlocked phone options.
I understand that We have only seen Ubuntu Phone running on the Galaxy Nexus, however I was wondering if any Pantech users would be able to estimate the possible availabilty for Ubuntu on Pantech Burst or other devices in the next year?