# Does Ubuntu support the CDMA version of the Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samsung, galaxy-nexus

Looking at the list of supported devices, I see that GSM Galaxy Nexus devices (takju and yakju) are supported but nothing about the CDMA (toro/Verizon or toroplus/Sprint) versions of the Galaxy Nexus.

Are these devices (toro and toroplus) so very different from takju or yakju (other than radios)? Will I be able to flash Ubuntu Touch to a toro or toroplus device?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: This is a perfectly clear question. Thank you for asking.

Comment: Sadly it is still a duplicated of http://askubuntu.com/q/236276/169736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a port for Toro, the call and data isn't working but Im sure it will soon. Just factory reset and flash both files with twrp or cwm.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?s=546095c024512bf2b366ddf1271e6e13&t=2159515

Have fun.