# how to install ubuntu on my Samsung galaxy s2

Tags: installation, samsung, smartphone

How to install ubuntu on my Samsung galaxy s2?

I do not know if I understood correctly. Can I install Ubuntu on a Samsung Galaxy S2 or is there a program to run on the Android?

Comment: And of http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-touch-support

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu touch is pretty much a device OS by itself. You will lose all of your Android data, and applications if you install it. Please read the [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) for more details and installation instructions.