# Ubuntu Touch Manual Installation

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, documentation

I want to install ubuntu touch on my google nexus 4. I want manual installation to be done.
Please let me know which files should i download from the following url given:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/current/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware will the Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 2):

The following page details how to do a manual install of the Ubuntu Touch preview. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Manual_Installation

Comment: It says "Get the matching hardware specific zip for your device from the Ubuntu cdimage server". Please let me know which file is for google nexus 4.

Answer (score 1):

The codename for nexus 4 is "mako". download the file with "+mako.zip"

Answer (score 0):

I the device is unknown but supported, with your device cable connected you can perform a

```
phablet-flash -D
```

and it will download the `zip` files for your device. The console output will provide an indication of where it's downloading to.