# Does Ubuntu Phone support the Nokia N9?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nokia

Would be possible to use Ubuntu Phone with Nokia N9?
MeeGo OS didn't meet any expectation. I'd love to keep my phone but replace MeeGo with Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What hardware will the Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/q/236276/114818)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Only a few devices with Android preinstalled are supported.