# Installing Ubuntu For Android

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sony, ubuntu-for-android

Is there anyway I can install Ubuntu for Android **alongside** android by dual-booting it? is it compatible with Xperia U?

Xperia U has **`NovaThor U8500`** chipset

Comment: Please differentiate clearly between original products and fakes. The Samsung tag is completely out of place in your question. A fake is not the same product of inferior quality, it's a completely different product.

Comment: These original parts all together cost more than 25$ and they wouldn't break so easily. These are _not_the_same_. What's your point anyway? You want us to recommend you products, that almost instantly break and you are aware of? We would be a poor kind of community if we do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Ubuntu alongside android was not released. Most probably ubuntu edge going to be the first device (if the funding success).

The closest one is available now is ubuntu touch. This is not alongside Android. It is complete replacement of android. Regarding support see [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/q/236276/35775)

Ubuntu touch installation is possible only if there is CM10 build (the lower level abstraction ) is available & Bootloader is unlocked.

If the above conditionis met , the you need to port the image. For porting see ubuntu touch porting guide. see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Though the device list already include s4, those will not work for your device as the hardware is different and so as the drivers.

Answer (score 2):

No, Ubuntu for Android has not been released, so you can't install it.

Comment: Let's try it again: You can't install software that you don't have access to XD

Comment: no it's available out there, i think it's called ubuntu touch for the preview version XD

Comment: No. Ubuntu Touch is something else. Ubuntu Touch is a full phone/tablet UI with the goal of convergence next year. Ubuntu for Android is the Ubuntu desktop on top of Android. Not the same thing.