# Ubuntu for Phones or new Android OS

Tags: hardware, ubuntu-touch, android

so I got a barely used phone from my buddy. He had thought it was stolen just after buying it, but has recently found it and given it to me because it has a little port for a SIM card. Since I have T-mobile I thought that I would simply have to root and unlock the phone via some online tutorial and pop the SIM in, but to no avail. I can't find much info on the phone and it seems to only run CDMA. Nothing happens when I insert my SIM card. It is the ZTE Engage V8000. It is a Muve Music phone from Cricket.

I was wondering if I could just put Ubuntu for Phones on it and it would detect my SIM. Would that work? I feel like Ubuntu for Phones might be thrown out there enough for it to work. If not, how can I get my SIM card to work on the Android OS? Do I need to install a whole new operating system? Is there any way that I can use this phone? My current phone doesn't seem to have a strong enough antenna for my area. It's a cheapy knock-off from Hong Kong so anything else would work. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I can see where you are coming from, but I feel as though I am asking something only slightly different. I need more specific information that I cannot find anywhere else, and that is not included in the question deemed a possible duplicate (I had already reviewed that Q&A and was not satisfied). I need more-so to know whether I can immediately use the Ubuntu-Touch software for a phone via GSM network. I also need to know if I can even use the phone here. I came to this site because it is by-far the best. A lot of questions get marked as "duplicates", but we need more-specific, guiding info.

Comment: I'm not sure your question is actually destined for here, though, you're not asking a question about Ubuntu Touch but rather a question about whether using Android, or using some other OS, and not an actual question about ubuntu-touch or android.  Also the fact you're using a cheap knock-off phone might also be the source of your issues :P

Comment: Well the cheap knock-off phone is unrelated to the problem. That was just to show that I was desperate to be able to use this new phone. And I sort of understand what you mean. I am also running Ubuntu 13.04 and would need help installing the OS using Ubuntu since everything out there is for Windows or Macintosh.

Comment: Then I think you are looking for the specifications to run Ubuntu Touch right? If it's like that check [What hardware will support Ubuntu Touch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find ubuntu phone version for this phone so you may need to port it. Try using XChat and connect to the developer's channel for more info.

In-depth support

There’s a wide variety of support resources, from Q&As to real-time support, for developers no matter what their level of experience with Ubuntu:

Real-time communication: #ubuntu-phone IRC channel on Freenode

E-mail discussion: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone

Developer Q&A: www.askubuntu.com

Project coordination, specs and guidelines, handbook: wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuPhone/CoreApps

Project hosting and actual code on Launchpad: launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone-coreapps/