# When can i download ubuntu for a tablet?

Tags: android, tablet, kindle

When will it be possible to download ubuntu to install on tablet devices? I've got a few tablets which i would love to install ubuntu onto. For instance I've got a kindle which I hate having to go on amazon to download aps. It would be cool if i could install ubuntu on it as then I would have the freedom to do things I want without having the hassle of amazon watching what I download.

Comment: The process of installing Ubuntu is different for each type of tablet. You would have better luck if you either asked separate questions including the make and model of each tablet, or if you searched the internet for guides for each one.

Comment: I have a Amazon Kindle Fire. The one before HD.

Comment: Thanks for the link. looks like ill have to wait till 2014.

Comment: OP is looking for a way to install Ubuntu on a tablet. The Ubuntu Phones and Tablets are going to have Ubuntu preinstalled by the OEM.

Comment: possible duplicate [What hardware will support Ubuntu Touch](http://askubuntu.com/q/236276/169736)

Comment: @searchfgold6789 can you specify please: OP? OEM? for non english native, it is difficult to follow

Comment: What I meant was, your question is not answered by knowing when Ubuntu Touch will officially be out.

Answer (score 1):

For installing Ubuntu Touch (the developer edition, just a preview) on the Kindle Fire and other tablets, see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices). That is a list of all the currently supported touch devices. In the column on the right you can find instructions on how to install Ubuntu on the device.

An odd guide on how to do this with the Desktop version (?): [here](http://www.yumapk.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-04-on-amazon-kindle-fire-hd.html)

Comment: For example, this is the page for the Kindle Fire 1st gen: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/otter and 2nd gen: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/otter2