# How do I get Ubuntu for tablets?

Tags: tablet

It says on the website that Ubuntu for tablets runs on Intel x64 hardware. Great! Where can I download it please?

Nick

Answer (score 0):

There have been posted a similar question - see [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/341919/277426)
Also you may find useful [Installing Ubuntu for Devices](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) link.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have looked at the links you posted but they are all about Android tablets. I am referring to the page here

http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/operators-and-oems

If it is ready for OEMs, why can't we download it for Windows PC tablets same as we can for server or desktop editions? Seems like a PC tablet should be the easiest target given that Ubuntu is originally for PCs.

Desktop Ubuntu is awful on a PC tablet so I have been waiting for a couple of years now for Ubuntu touch and Canonical says it is ready so where is it please? We're past 14.04.

Nick

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/how-to-flash-ubuntu-touch-from-windows.html) is what you're looking for? The article says it's about how to install Ubuntu Touch if you're using Windows. I hope this will help :)

Comment: I also found this thread [Will Ubuntu 14.04 support tablets?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214936) - it seems like it works only for the officially listed tablets. it's a pity.

Comment: Thanks again Ksiencha. I thought it must be the case but the PR lies on the page I linked to made me think that the x86 version must be available somehow (not entirely unreasonable given that it actually says it is available for x86 on that page). Will wait for 14.10 I guess. Thanks for your patience and all your help.