# Can i install Ubuntu on a the toshiba c55ta Touch screen?

Tags: toshiba

Can i install Ubuntu on a the Toshiba c55ta Touch screen?
If yes should i install 12.04 or 13.10?
it has win 8  64bit and runs fine

Comment: I have the same computer, Toshiba C55t-A, and can't get Linux to install at all even after turning off "Secure Boot" in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about Unity 8 coming in a future release, with full touch support. However, this is almost certainly a year away. I've got a Unity 8 phone simulation on my laptop and is is really *really* alpha. But, for some more ideas: [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110766&p=12504549#post12504549) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349154/supported-laptop-with-touchscreen) might help you. Other than that, not really sure. Sorry!