# Help for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can you install Ubuntu Touch on any Android phone?

I would like to try it on my Xperia E C1505/C1504 phone. If I do then can I go back to using Android?

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu for Android](https://web.archive.org/web/20140228054240/http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android) will provide a way of running Ubuntu alongside Android off of a smartphone when docked. For more information about Ubuntu for Android, visit the link and watch the short video there, *What is Ubuntu for Android?*.

Also look at the answers to the question: [What hardware will the Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-touch-support).