# Can i install ubuntu in my xperia pro?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Will my sony erricson xperia pro support Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,your `sony erricson xperia pro` doesn't support Ubuntu OS.see [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-touch-support) link for supported phones,available applications,etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check the folloiwng web site to know whether your device is compatible or not
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices