# Is there a "Live" Ubuntu version for Android phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, system-installation

I would like to know that if Ubuntu can be installed on an Android phone without wiping out the current installation. Something like the Live CD for desktops?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu can't be installed on an Android phone without wiping out the current installation.Please [check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-ubuntu-touch-support) that your phone supports Ubuntu or not.

If you want to try  Ubuntu  for phones,then install [Ubuntu touch Emulator](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator) on your Ubuntu PC.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the app. Go to Google Play store and search under "Linux" and "Ubuntu". As an example "Linux Deploy" seems to be a good app.

If you have a Galaxy Nexus you can go to http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install  but this will replace your Android OS

If your just interested in testing things out try an Ubuntu Phone emulator: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/11/ubuntu-touch-emulator-released