# Ubuntu Touch for cubieboard3/Cubietruck?

Tags: 13.10, system-installation, ubuntu-touch

I was wondering weather it would be possible to install the `saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.tar.gz` system onto a Cubieboard3 (CubieTruck). The processor is an AllWinner A20 (ARMv7 Architecture, which I know is supported). I know it is possible to install Lubuntu Desktop or Server onto it via:

http://docs.cubieboard.org/tutorials/ct1/installation/install_lubuntu_desktop_server_to_sd_card"

I have the file saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip currently downloaded onto my Windows machine. I do have an Ubuntu system available if that is necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware do Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-do-ubuntu-touch-support)