# Install / Dual-boot Ubuntu on a Android tablet?

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 (SM-T210), I would love to install Ubuntu on it. Is it currently possible? And is anyone developing a rom?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu wiki has a page on devices that are supported at https:/www.wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install. Currently the only *officially* supported devices are:

Quote from Supported devices:

> The table below lists the supported devices and their corresponding
>   factory images, should you want to switch back to Android. The images
>   can be found here.
>
> **Note**: We currently do not support the newer '2013' Nexus 7.
>
> ```
> Device         Codename  Factory firmware from Google  Status
>
> Galaxy Nexus  maguro     takju or yakju                Stable (build #100)
>
> Nexus 4       mako       occam                         Stable (build #100)
>
> Nexus 7       grouper    nakasi or nakasig             Pre-release
>
> Nexus 10      manta      mantaray                      Pre-release
> ```

thus your Galaxy Tab 3.7.0 isn't *officially* supported by the official builds. So, no.

This is similar/duplicate of this question: [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-ubuntu-touch-support)