# info for OS on new hand sets

Tags: ubuntu-touch

How can I get Ubuntu for some new mobile device as are planning to launch new mobile device, what about installation of additional Apps, what built in features & Apps are to be offered with OS, expecting detailed info.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what kind of new mobile device. Thanks

Comment: You may see a list of officially supported phone devices and unofficially community supported devices at http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-ubuntu-touch-support .  As to features and applications, please visit the Ubuntu Touch blog for official information at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch is the source for official information on special features, new apps, and other details. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices lists devices officially supported, and also known to but but with community support only.