# How safe is ubuntu touch on nexus 7 2012

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I don't know if the version provided by ubuntu for grouper is complete, or if its safe.
I just want a portable Linux(Ubuntu) device. That can handle everything that my PC can(quite easily.)
Any will grouper receive any major updates from cannonical ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware will Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: Question is about **ongoing support**, it already was *supported*.

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu Touch is still in development, and in beta.

The (older) **Nexus 7** (gen 1, '2012 model', '*grouper*') is no longer supported as *reference hardware*. You can run the older beta build versions, but will not be receiving (timely) updates, bug fixes, and/or further improvements.

### Conclusions:

- It is not ready to use as a Linux device, to replace a PC;
- The **Nexus 7** (gen 1) is not currently supported;
- And NO (at time of writing), '*grouper'* will not receive major updates (from Canonical).

---

***All subject to change, and vagaries of market (and marketing).***