# i can't download ubuntu dual boot on galaxy nexus

Tags: dual-boot, galaxy-nexus

When I try to install Ubuntu Dual Boot on my Galaxy Nexus, I get this error message when it starts to download:

[image: ubuntu dual boot]

Please help, I would like to download ubuntu phone on my galaxy nexus

Answer (score 5):

The error message is very clear: you don't have enough space. Free up some space!

Answer (score 0):

You need to free up space or your device - you can use a bog standard android file manager for this (you may need to delete some large apps as well) - though it can help to have a program such as a [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) which shows which files are taking up space:

[image]

For installation, [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/q/236276/178596) should be helpful