# How to install Ubuntu Touch OS on a bricked N900 phone?

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, system-installation, smartphone

I recently got interested and bought a used [N900](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_N900), because of the many cool things I heard about it. While trying to install an application through HAM, I think I made a mistake and now the phone is 'bootlooping' (maybe because of kernel_power).

As I was reading how to flash the device, I saw Ubuntu Touch. Now instead of reverting back to Maemo 5, I wanted to try Ubuntu Touch as the new main phone OS.

How to install Ubuntu on a bricked phone, using Windows 7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu on a mobile is much more complicated than on a PC, you need an image especially made for your mobile. Ubuntu is not really ready for phones (yet) and the most advanced images are listed here but there seems to be no progress on yours:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Comment: thanks, that reply was quicker than the old askubuntu experience I had on the old site :) so anyways, before flashing the N900 back to Maemo, any other mobile OS suggestions? Hopefully something newer with ample support. I've seen Kubuntu mobile but I'm not sure if it's stable enough on the phone side

Comment: I guess the only one you could make to work is Android: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1233519