# Can I format my Kindle Fire (1st Gen) and install Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, system-installation, kindle

I have an old 1st Gen Kindle Fire that I do not use often anymore. I shattered the screen a year or so ago, and it was too expensive to fix at the time. Parts are cheaper now so I ordered off Amazon and plan to replace the glass.

The OS on those, though... it sucks. I really don't like any aspect of it, and want to just wipe it out. Can I somehow format the disk and install something like Ubuntu Touch? I've looked around, but everything I find ends up being a lot of clicks through different forum posts to get all the necessary steps.

I'm rather new to Linux and just installed Ubuntu on my laptop about a month ago. I'm still learning my way around a bit. But it would make this otherwise useless tablet 100,000x better to have a decent OS that will actually give me some functionality.

Has anyone done this before? Will the hardware support it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware will Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: No, that thread doesn't answer my question @david6

Answer (score 2):

At this moment, there are no stable versions of Ubuntu Touch for the Kindle Fire 1st generation. But there is an unstable preview of it by Hashcode but I don't see if it's going to be updated soon because he is making a new rom called OtterX:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2169327

There are apps to download Linux on the tablet with Android still installed:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid

Also, you should try the Kitkang roms by Euroskank:
 http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2266248

Comment: Also, try gederom. It's ICS-based but still a pretty good rom

Comment: So I'm coming back to this a year later, thought I might give a slight update.

I ended up getting CyanogenMod on the Fire pretty easily. I honestly don't use it as much as I thought I would, and have mainly gone back to using the original OS and just using it as an e-reader only. But since no one has the unlock codes needed from Verizon to root Lollipop on my M8 yet, I think I may tool around with the Kindle a bit more soon. Looks like Hashcode has been abandoned in the last year, so I'll have to find some other cool projects for it. I'll report back.

Comment: // , Heheh. Euroskank. Heheh. Also, if you like Hacking, Verizon is prooooobably not the optimal provider.

Comment: // , Where did you find CyanogenMod to run on this? What version? What Kindle Fire model #?