# Ubuntu Touch on HTC Desire X

Tags: ubuntu-touch, htc

I want to install Ubuntu Touch in HTC Desire X. Can you please let me know whether this is possible or not.?

If it's provide me some guide to install and if not, let Ubuntu Developers to work on Desire X product too.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to install Ubuntu one in htc desire x as far to my knowledge.Even I too use htc desire x.