# Installing Ubuntu on Samsung

Tags: system-installation, samsung, phone

Can i install Ubuntu on a samsung GT-M3710, it doesn't have android, it has SHP.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please look at this question: [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support). Ubuntu Touch is still in development, so has to be ported to most devices.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung GT-M3710 is not officially supported and looking at the hardware of your phone its seems reasonably difficult pursuit to install Ubuntu touch. So, the answer to your question would be NO.

You will have to test yourself and post back.