# Using ubuntu-device-flash on a Nexus N7 only installs the rescue system

Tags: boot, system-installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Following [this developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) guide I flashed my Nexus 7 via `# ubuntu-device-flash --channel=trusty --bootstrap`, got this [1] output, but after rebooting the following from the **Install Ubuntu** section doesn't happen here:

*Then, the parts of the images are deployed to the device. Ubuntu is deployed to the devices as a “recovery” image. Then, the device boots from the recovery image and installs Ubuntu as the normal OS. Finally, the device boots into Ubuntu for devices.*

It only boots into the normal bootloader, and Ubuntu is only present when I select "Recovery mode". This menu has an "**-install zip**" option where I guess I must continue, but I can not find out where I would find the relevant zip-file or how to apply it exactly. I can see the device though and use `adb ..` to reboot or start a shell.

1:

```
# ubuntu-device-flash --channel=trusty --bootstrap                                                              
2014/08/10 22:23:41 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2014/08/10 22:23:42 Device is |grouper|
2014/08/10 22:23:42 Flashing version 294 from trusty channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device grouper
/root/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/trusty/grouper/version-294.tar.xz
/root/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz
/root/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz
/root/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-08c13901d732c4ff24c342fd62f949ef4d92dbfe4bbdd9b3aee5df327619d30b.tar.xz
2014/08/10 22:24:17 Start pushing /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/trusty/grouper/version-294.tar.xz to device
2014/08/10 22:24:17 Start pushing /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2014/08/10 22:24:17 Start pushing /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2014/08/10 22:24:17 Start pushing /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-08c13901d732c4ff24c342fd62f949ef4d92dbfe4bbdd9b3aee5df327619d30b.tar.xz to device
2014/08/10 22:24:17 Start pushing /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-035dbe1b5088d07d386c1c6a7833c029ae1ac5ab2e3b1a86a1a3571f2566362c.tar.xz to device
2014/08/10 22:24:17 Done pushing /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/trusty/grouper/version-294.tar.xz to device
2014/08/10 22:24:17 Done pushing /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2014/08/10 22:24:17 Done pushing /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2014/08/10 22:25:12 Done pushing /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-08c13901d732c4ff24c342fd62f949ef4d92dbfe4bbdd9b3aee5df327619d30b.tar.xz to device
2014/08/10 22:29:01 Done pushing /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-035dbe1b5088d07d386c1c6a7833c029ae1ac5ab2e3b1a86a1a3571f2566362c.tar.xz to device
2014/08/10 22:29:01 Created ubuntu_command: /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu_commands037385836
2014/08/10 22:29:01 Rebooting into recovery to flash
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there is only limited device support for Ubuntu Touch:

`> 2014/08/10 22:23:42 Device is |grouper|`

[What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

also http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/devices/

Comment: I noticed that a _grouper_ image is only present here https://system-image.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/trusty/ but not for utopic/ or devel/. But if it is there, should it not at least install? Is there a way to revert to a state when this device was still supported? Or manually copy files over, given I have an adb shell?