# How to run ubuntu on android?

Tags: android

I was on the Canonical website and I clicked on products, upon clicking on that I saw under Ubuntu there was a picture of ubuntu on a phone and tablet http://www.canonical.com/products as seen here. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you saw was Ubuntu for mobiles [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone), it's not installed on android, bu instead of android.

You can install Ubuntu (arm) on sd card and chroot to it, if you install vnc server then you can use vnc viewer on android and use all the apps Ubuntu has to offer. Easiest way to do that is by installing android app (Complete Linux Installer for example).