# Ubuntu mobile for Samsung 12" tablet

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, ubuntu-touch

How can I go about putting Ubuntu on my [Samsung Galaxy Note Pro 12.2](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/SM-P9000ZKVXAR) with dual boot options? That way I can have a computer when needed and Android on the other.

I have tried to Google it, but keep coming to pages listing just the Nexus devices and I honestly just want to use Ubuntu on a Samsung tablet.

Specifications:
⠀Processor: Samsung Exynos 5420 Octa 1.8 GHz (ARM-based SoC with integrated Mali GPU)
⠀Memory: 3GB
⠀Graphics adapter: ARM Mali-T628 MP6
⠀Display: 12.2 inch 16:10, 2560x1600 pixel, capacitive touchscreen, LCD
⠀Hard disk: 32GB eMMC Flash, 32GB , 22.82GB free

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you don't. There are certainly no official images for anything non-Nexus and currently no user contributed ports for your device, either. There are options for the older Notes that perhaps could be hacked, but that's not a very functional solution, especially considering most of the ports are incomplete. You can see the device list [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices). You can also find a more general answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/259320/237241).