# Ubuntu On Nokia C5-00

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch

How to install Ubuntu on Nokia C5-00 mobile? Provide a step by step process of installation on Nokia system symbian mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can not install ubuntu os in Nokia C5-00 mobile.

It is because the Nokia C5-00 mobile's hardware is not sufficient to install Ubuntu os.

Click [here](http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support) to know what hardware does ubuntu supports.