# Will the graphics tablets Genius EasyPen i405 and Genius Easy Pen i405x work on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics-tablet

I want to buy one of these two graphics tablets. I've heard that the i405x model is newer so I would prefer to buy this one, however I've also heard that there can be problems with making it work on Linux (or maybe this issue has been fixed?) and I haven't heard that anyone had any problems with the i405 model.
Does any of you has one of these models? Do they work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: No, this thread doesn't provide an answer to my question because I am asking about graphics tablets, not tablets like Nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have bought a Genius EasyPen i405x and it works! I am pretty sure i405 should also work because on the forums it seems that more people have problems with i405x compatibility with Ubuntu than i405.