# Is there a way we android users download ubuntu and instal it to our phones?

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

I was thinking since ubuntu for androids has already been delevoped, why isnt there a way we can all instal it to our androids?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: I totally agree with your point of view and even I did not get a satisfactory answer. May be a marketing strategy! Since device support is very less comparing to destop edition which is available to every hardware even for portables.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu isn't an app.  It's an operating system.  You already have an OS on your phone which allows you to do many things including downloading and running various apps.

People often change or modify their android OS by burning a different image.

When you burn a different image to your android/phone you risk bricking it.  If this happens, of course you've voided the warren-tee and would need to get a new phone.

At present the list of Android devices is short.  If you want an Ubuntu device strong enough you might consider purchasing a supported one.

Look at this ubuntu development support site:
[Installing Ubuntu on devices|Ubuntu Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

Only one secure option which I found is Android app [Complete Linux Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid) from Play Store.

Yes, for some devices there are sollutions, but that's are dangerous if you are not advanced user which love ADB etc. and (mainly) biggest reason why not do that is old repositories for some solutions, such as Ubuntu 13.04 for Nexus 7 2012.

I use Complete Linux Installer with installed Debian with VNC, I can connect to tablet from deskop,... It is not ideal solution, but maybe best.