# Can Ubuntu be install on android device?

Tags: android

I am using android phone but i love **Ubuntu**, to use **Ubuntu** on desktop pc but now I want to use on my phone.

So if it can be installed on phone, then can some provide the steps or web link of tuts to install **Ubuntu**.

I have seen many tuts of **android device**.

[www.techsnext.com](http://www.techsnext.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 0):

You need few step:

1.unlock your bootloader

2.flash with custom kernel that support Ubuntu and root your device.(also you can flash ROM)

3.copy ubuntu img file in your sd card .(also you need to configure your Ubuntu by terminal)

4.install a vpn and connect Ubuntu. Your done!

Requirements: 
dual core processor and 1GB ram minmum.

The details of how to install Ubuntu on an Android phone are given [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)