# Pocket PCs that run Ubuntu?

Tags: portable

Are there pocket PCs out there (as of 2014) that can run Ubuntu 14.04?  It looks like the pocket PC market has been dead since 2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: What's yogur definition of pocket pc? There are a lot of pc's in a stick around there running android and Linux distros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the traditional sense no, however AMD does have what I guess you could say is a pocket PC coming in the future (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO0IbIiaAVM) If you mean pocket PC as in really small PCs then there are Intel NUCs and Gigabyte Brixs. They are I guess 'Pocket PCs' As 'xangua' said it really depends on what your definition of a pocket PC is