# Stable Ubuntu build for Sony Ericssion NEO-V MT11i

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sony, phone

I am new to Ubuntu world. But very much interested to have Ubuntu on my Sony Ericssion NEO-V MT11i-Haida. Can some one please guide me. As of now, it's on CM11.

Step by step would be great, and helpful.

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install Ubuntu Touch specially designed for mobile devices. According to the wiki site your phone is supported. Go here for instructions and more info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/haida