# Preinstalled touch image

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm not a total newbie, I've done a lot of things on Linux (Ubuntu 12.4), have a good basic knowledge of terminal, but I' just downloaded `/Desktop/vivid-preinstalled-touch-i386.tar.gz`. So how do I turn this into an ISO?

Have already extracted everything.

Comment: if you want to make the iso to install on a device, try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in Terminal (providing it with the name of the output image file, the name of the directory(s) to copy into the image, and options as desired):

```
mkisofs -J -r -o your.iso /name/of/directory/with/your/files/
```