# Can I install Ubuntu Touch to Samsung Tab 8.9 Lte?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to install Ubuntu Touch on my Samsung Tab 8.9 LTE GT-P7320?

Comment: It would be a lot of work and you really would need to know what you're doing. I'm guessing given the question it would be a bit of an effort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 0):

Not according to Ubuntu's wiki, no. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Comment: I hope this model of samsung Tab will be included in the list of devices.