# Ubuntu Touch's free download

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can I download **Ubuntu Touch** from any site or do I have to buy it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: @muru He's not asking what Ubuntu Touch supports, he's asking whether it's free.

Comment: @Zacharee1 When somebody asks "Can I download", it's implied that they are also asking "Where do I download it from" and related questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can download Ubuntu Touch 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) Daily Builds from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/).