# Can I install ubuntu touch in konka KM7011BK tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to install ubuntu touch on konka tablet with 512MB of RAM and 4GB of storage? It also has a microSD card slot which can be expandable upto 32GB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect it to work out of the box right now. There may be compatibility issues:

- not being able to connect to the internet
- simply not booting
- crashing / unstability

I would advice against it, but you can always try and let us know the results.

It's not only the specifications that are important for Ubuntu Touch, it needs drivers for the hardware too. There is a big chance some of these will be missing. Every tablet is different.