# Can I install Ubuntu Touch on a HP TouchPad?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchpad, hp, 15.04, hp-touchpad

I have already tried searching around, and the only solutions I can find are outdated and no longer work. Does anyone have an up-to-date way of putting Ubuntu Touch onto a HP TouchPad? I have a laptop running Ubuntu 15.04 that I can use to install it onto the TouchPad, but I do not have access to a Windows machine, so anything that requires Windows is out of the question.

I already know that people have previously been able to install Ubuntu Touch on a HP TouchPad, I want to know how to do so, as I can't find any guides and I have no idea what my first step would be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: It is not a duplicate - I already know that people have previously been able to install Ubuntu Touch on a HP TouchPad, I want to know how to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately Touch on HP Touchpad seems to be a back-of-the-queue for developers, (which is strange considering the number of TP's out there - natural potential hosts for Ubuntu Touch, especially now that WebOS is out of support).

I'm not going to agree that the "solutions are outdated" - get yourself over to XDA-Devs (specifically [Ubuntu Touch 13.10 Saucy on the HP Touchpad DUAL BOOT ANDROID](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2426924)) and you'll see that there's still some interest out there - last post April 2015.

As to first steps, and especially doing it properly, (ie without Windows), that might be tricky. I'm thinking that Novacomm (required) should work via Wine, failing that FreeDOS VM?. Once that's in place the instructions on the first page look reasonable, although I think you'll end up with WebOS/Android/Ubuntu, rather than just Ubuntu (like I guess you want).

I've now got two "surplus to requirements" TP's so it's maybe possible that at least one of them will get the Ubuntu Touch treatment. If I get the chance to do the "upgrade" then I'll feed back on this.

Comment: So yeah all the links are broken on that - so I tried building it myself, using Ubuntu's guide. I found the device-specific blobs thanks go the existing port that I couldn't get to work, I added the repos as a manifest tenderloin.xml and phablet-dev-bootstrap sync'd up which fetched all the repos and placed them in the appropriate place. Then later when I get to 'lunch' I get told 'Can not find config makefile for 'cm_tenderloin' and then something else about manifests (I can post the full output here later when I get home). I can't seem to find what the issue is?