# Will Ubuntu work on my Amazon Fire Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, phone

It seems to fit the hardware requirements and there are plenty of guides on how to install on an Android, but I wanted to learn as much as I can before rooting my phone and possibly installing it.

I'm not sure if this is relevant or not but my carrier is AT&T, so if I do root my phone and install Ubuntu should I expect any problems with calling or texting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: I'd just to point out that rooting has nothing to do with installing a ROM.

Comment: Thank you, I'm somewhat familiar with Ubuntu as a desktop OS but I really have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to smartphones.  I thought that I had to root the phone in order to wipe and install a new OS.

Answer (score 1):

In order to install Ubuntu OS on any Android device you will need to have an unlocked/unlockable bootloader. The Amazon Fire phone does not offer an unlockable bootloader and at this time, the development community hasn't found a bootloader unlock exploit.

So in short, there is not, at this time any way to flash Ubuntu OS to your device. Amazon does not permit 3rd party firmware and merely rooting will not permit such things. Root access only gives you write access to the system partition, it does not, however, allow you to re-flash device partitions. Especially the boot (or kernel) partition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Fire OS has been somewhat of a disappointment...