# Can I use Ubuntu touch on my Samsung Galaxy Grand duos gt-i9082?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I like to learn linux based operating system. If not, what are the steps to make it work in this device? I am really interested in getting Ubuntu touch in my phone. I rooted my phone and i had tried custom roms also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For learning using a linux based OS, I would recommend to install Ubuntu (or a different distribution, if you want) on a desktop pc, since Ubuntu touch is still kind of experimental and it will be easier to get help for the well established desktop OS.

You might want to try it first in a virtual machine, if you want to keep your old OS and are scared to mess with the partitions for a dual-boot setup.
There are many tutorials on how to do that online.

If you want to install Ubuntu touch on your phone, you should read this question:
[What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: I did a dual boot in my Macbook Pro and I am using Ubuntu 15.04 right now. I like the linux based OS. And thanks  for the link. I want to try Ubuntu Touch OS in my android phone. I dont know anything porting to a new phone at all... But i will try to learn... Thanks for ur support Wayne_Yux!!!