# Can i install ubuntu touch on my windows 8.1 toshiba encore 2 tablet?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-touch, tablet

Can i install ubuntu touch on my windows 8.1 toshiba encore 2 tablet ?
Please ?
I just won this tablet and i want to install android or ubuntu touch in it !
Please tell me how .
I tried to create a flash drive with android for baytrail i've install the 32bit efi but it boots on a efi terminal and doesn't start installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 1):

A quick check of the [List of currently supported devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) reveals that there is currently no installable image for your device.