# Its regarding htc one M7 root and install ubuntu

Tags: htc

I want to completely remove android from my htc one m7 and want to install Ubuntu in my phone but I want this to be done in one step and I don't want make root once and etc., things so please help me.... and please don't suggest me xda developers because there is a long process in it and I want it in one step.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 0):

There is no one step process for installing Ubuntu Touch on your device right now. However you can try to port it to your device and then install it. 
Please start [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/).
Please note that this is a long process too. It will require time and patience.
If you are unwilling to spend so much time, I would suggest waiting until somebody else ported ubuntu touch to your device and then installing it.