# With to try ubuntu touch on my tablet

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, android, tablet

[link to my tablet](http://www.colorovo.eu/products-en/tablets-en/citytab-lite-8-2-0.html?product_id=3852)

I am horrified that android has only 1G of 8G for apps on this device (Unusable). I truly wish to try ubuntu on it if at all possible.
Tried rooting with kingo root, kingroot, iroot installed app on android method all fail.

following [the ubuntu guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)

Tablet is reset to factory settings, no data loss.

```
    $ adb shell grep ro.product.name /system/build.prop > mydevicedata \
&& adb shell grep build.id /system/build.prop >> mydevicedata \
&& adb shell grep ro.product.device /system/build.prop >> mydevicedata
```

gives this result

```
$ cat mydevicedata 
ro.product.name=ABM8000NBD
ro.build.id=JRO03C
ro.product.device=ABM8000NBD
```

I am stuck at Headline "About adb and fastboot"

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

only reboots device,

I believe there is no combination of power and volume buttons trying to get in bootloader tablet just shuts down when power is pressed during boot.

Device is visible in adb

```
$ adb devices 
List of devices attached 
0123456789ABCDEF    device
```

`fastboot devices`

returns nothing since I can not get into bootloader.

Miracle is that
 `adb reboot recovery`
works and I am able to get into recovery

[image: sideload]

Can anything be done with `adb sideload`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put support for Colorovo tablet never even existed.