# How to install ubuntu on ASUS Fonepad 7 Tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, asus

I'm using ASUS Fonepad 7 ME175CG Android Tablet. I'm tried of using Android OS & I don't like it much because of preinstalled bloatware apps. I want to try ubuntu touch or ubuntu os on my tablet. Please tell me if there is any possible way to do this.

Comment: It's not impossible, but might not be easy, ...duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for asking a duplicate question, I'm a fresh user on this site.

Comment: It's ok, no trouble at all.

Comment: Can anyone give me tutorial for installing Ubuntu touch on my device?