# Can I install Ubuntu Touch on unsupported device

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I read everywhere different opinions about installing Ubuntu Touch on unsupported devices. I have a Hibook Pro Chuwi and want to install Ubuntu Touch.
My question is this: At present is it possible to install Ubuntu Touch on my Hibook Pro?
Link: http://en.chuwi.com/product/items/Chuwi-HiBook-pro.html

Comment: Why would you want to run a limited version of Ubuntu on a PC that *can run full x86 Ubuntu*?!

Comment: I know this list but when I see this kind of video I allow myself to doubt that this is impossible
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3PUYoa1c9M](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3PUYoa1c9M)

Comment: I would suggest that you consider using a full Ubuntu setup instead - this device may be able to support a standard Ubuntu installation (with PAE).  Note also that the hardware list is specific for Ubuntu Touch, but the community has been trying to port it to some other devices (please see [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support) for more details and links to the Ubuntu Wiki for this).

Comment: Because I would like to use this tablet to watch movies ect .. and when I plug in a keyboard I spend desktop version