# How do I install Ubuntu Touch on a touch screen enabled laptop?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, laptop, touchscreen

I have a Dell Inspiron 11 (Model No.3158) laptop with touch screen support.
Where can I download Ubuntu Touch for 64-bit architecture? Can I install it on a HDD partition alongside Windows10 and Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: There is no official release for x86 yet. You can just download 16.10 or [17.04 beta2](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-17.04-beta2-desktop-amd64.iso), install it, and select Unity 8 at the login screen. The way you install it is about the same as 14.04.

Comment: @mikewhatever Don't use it in 16.10, most development on Unity 8 is done in 16.04 or 17.04. 16.10 is, even though it was shipped with Unity 8 as an option, kind of ignored with all the testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Touch is a mobile operating system and it works very different form traditional computer OSs. That means, that it's (currently) impossible to install it on x86 hardware. Ubuntu Touch actually uses an Android environment and hardware enablement stack to load all the proprietary firmware that is needed on the supported devices.

But that is not really a problem, because the goal with Ubuntu Touch is, to achieve Convergence, so that phones, tablets and PCs offer the same user experience and run (at some point in the future) the same software. They will become the same as soon as snaps, the new portable software packaging format, hits the shelves.

For now, you can just use Ubuntu with a touchscreen as it is. And if you want to see all the latest and greatest in Unity 8 (the next generation desktop environment that is used on Ubuntu Touch and will be default on Ubuntu soon) you can upgrade to 16.04 and set it up. Or you could install 17.04 beta or wait until 17.04 is released and check it out there.