# Can I still utilize the LTE band if I install Ubuntu on my Galaxy S7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'd like to install Ubuntu on my Galaxy S7 but I'd like to retain it's functionality as a cell phone too. I'd like to know if I'll be able to use the LTE band if I install Ubuntu? Thank you.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu Touch image for the Galaxy S7. See [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/q/236276/301745)

Comment: Oh wait, do you mean Ubuntu Desktop (AKA Ubuntu proper)?

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no port for the S7, you can't install Ubuntu Touch on it. See [here](https://devices.ubports.com/#/) for a list of supported devices. If you (or someone) created a port, the LTE band would be usable, both in the US and the rest of the world.

Since [UBports](https://ubports.com) is not porting to new devices until [Halium](https://halium.org) is finished, you might have to wait a while for someone else porting to it but for what it's worth, [here's the porting guide](https://wiki.ubports.com/wiki/UBports-Development-Information).